Multiple @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes
I know - based on different question here:

Multiple level @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes,
Deserialize with multiple levels of polymorphic type hierarchy

that in case of multiple inheritance (Car<Audi<Sedan), there can be used just one discriminator name: property = "carType".
But I have a different scenario that does now work for me - is this also not supported? - Scenario where I need to use also two discriminators, but not in "inheritance chain":
First level: carType (important note: Audi has field private ColorDiscriminator color;)
public enum CarType {

    AUDI, TOYOTA;

    public static final String AUDI_STR = "AUDI";
    public static final String TOYOTA_STR = "TOYOTA";
}

@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        property = "carType",
        visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Audi.class, name = CarType.AUDI_STR),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Toyota.class, name = CarType.TOYOTA_STR)
})
public abstract class CarDiscriminator {

    private CarType carType;

    public CarType getCarType () {
        return carType;
    }

    public void setCarType (CarType carType) {
        this.carType = carType;
    }
}

@JsonTypeName(CarType.AUDI_STR )
public class Audi extends CarDiscriminator {
  private ColorDiscriminator color;
  // ommited
}

@JsonTypeName(CarType.TOYOTA_STR)
public class Toyota extends CarDiscriminator {
  // ommited
}

Second level: colorType
public enum ColorType {

    BLUE, RED;

    public static final String BLUE_STR = "BLUE";
    public static final String RED_STR = "RED";
}

@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        property = "colorType",
        visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Blue.class, name = ColorType.BLUE_STR),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Red.class, name = ColorType.RED_STR)
})
public abstract class ColorDiscriminator {

    private ColorType colorType;

    public ColorType getColorType () {
        return colorType;
    }

    public void setColorType (ColorType colorType) {
        this.colorType = colorType;
    }
}

@JsonTypeName(ColorType.BLUE_STR)
public class Blue extends ColorDiscriminator {
  // ommited
}

@JsonTypeName(ColorType.RED_STR)
public class Red extends ColorDiscriminator {
  // ommited
}

In the generated swagger json (& ui) definition, I can see correctly just first oneOf carType: Audi | Toyota. But second colorType not. Generated json does not even contain Blue nor Red object definitions.
So consumed/produces JSONs could be like this:
Example 1:
{
    "carType": "AUDI",
    "attrAudi1" : "",
    "attrAudi2" : "",
    "attrAudi3" : "",
    "color": {
        "colorType" : "BLUE",
        "attrBlue1" : "",
        "attrBlue2" : "",
        "attrBlue3" : "",
    } 
}

Example 2:
{
    "carType": "AUDI",
    "attrAudi1" : "",
    "attrAudi2" : "",
    "attrAudi3" : "",
    "color": {
        "colorType" : "RED",
        "attrRed1" : "",
        "attrRed2" : "",
        "attrRed3" : "",
    } 
}

Example 3:
{
    "carType": "TOYOTA",
    "attrToyota1" : "",
    "attrToyota2" : "",
    "attrToyota3" : "",
    // no color attribute at all
}


Both links you've provided say that multiple inheritance is not supported, and, according to their official GitHub repository, it has been said several times that there are no plans for it.

This is not supported and there are no plans to extend type resolution in this direction.


support for multi-level resolution does not exist nor is planned. So chaining of definitions will not work.


It is not supported and there are no plans to support it. Do not design your system assuming this will be implemented.

On a side note, do not design classes with multiple inheritance in a language that only supports single inheritance. Furthermore, the objects you're modelling (car models and colors) do not share an inheritance relationship.
Inheritance is a relationship of specification where we go from a broader type (a base class) to a more specific one (a derived class). A derived class still shares the same properties and behavior of the base class, but it usually adds something to it, redefining its behavior to specialize it to the class of problems that the base class is designed to solve. In inheritance, an instance of the derived class is also said an instance of the base class. This relationship is often referred as is-a.
A typical example of is-a is Vehicle > Car > Audi, where a car is a vehicle, and an Audi is a car and is a vehicle. The same cannot be said in your code, where you're trying to map into a json a multiple inheritance relationship that doesn't exist. Just because an Audi is blue, that doesn't make it a color. That is just a property. If there actually was an inheritance relationship between the two, they should also share the same properties and behavior, which they don't. In general, when designing inheritance, we should ask ourselves "is X a Y?". If the answer is yes, then the two objects actually have an is-a relationship and should be designed as such; otherwise, if the answer is no, we should not force inheritance.

Update with Comments' Answer
After the clarifications given in the comments, I managed to better understand your goal and the problems you were having. So, for whoever is reading this answer, consider the example data types (car brands and colors) as general class markers. Do not focus on their actual relationship in a real world scenario.
The first problem you were experiencing was the missing serialization of the color field. When using the annotation @JsonTypeInfo with JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, it is the developer's duty to set the property's value via code. The property name in @JsonSubTypes is used by Jackson only during deserialization to understand which data type needs to be constructed. It is not used to automatically set its value during serialization. Here is a link to the issue #1669 on their GitHub repository, where it's pointed out how to correctly use the annotation with an existing property.
Another problem that might have contributed to the missing serialization of the color field (and even some others) is the lack of getter and setter methods. This point is solely based on the assumption that getters and setters might not be present in your code because of the omitted implementation. They actually might be there instead, but I'm adding this point just for completeness. In fact, Jackson is able to both serialize and deserialize a field if the class exhibits a getter and a setter (or even just a getter) for the field. If instead it's provided only a setter, the field can be only deserialized. Here is a link to an answer about Jackson's deserialization logic with also a great article from Baeldung.
Lastly, in order to not serialize the color field when this is null, you could use @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) before your CarDiscriminator class. This will make sure that every null field won't be serialized. However, if you want to ignore only the field color when null, but include every other null field, then you need to use the annotation @JsonFilter and implement a custom SimpleBeanPropertyFilter. I've provided an implementation at the end.
Here is a fixed implementation of your code. The visibility of the fields carType and colorType has been changed from private to protected so that the child classes can initialize them with the appropriate value. The child classes perform the initialization of the fields carType and colorType with a block initializer, so that the writing is compacted in a single point instead of being repeated for each constructor. Here is also a demo at OneCompiler that matches your expected output.
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
    property = "carType")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Audi.class, name = CarType.AUDI_STR),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Toyota.class, name = CarType.TOYOTA_STR)
})
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public abstract class CarDiscriminator {

    protected CarType carType;

    //default constructor
    
    //carType getter and setter
}

public class Audi extends CarDiscriminator {

    private int attrAudi1 = 1;
    private int attrAudi2 = 2;
    private int attrAudi3 = 3;
    private ColorDiscriminator color;

    {
        carType = CarType.AUDI;
    }

    public Audi() {}

    public Audi(int attrAudi1, int attrAudi2, int attrAudi3, ColorDiscriminator color) {
        this.attrAudi1 = attrAudi1;
        this.attrAudi2 = attrAudi2;
        this.attrAudi3 = attrAudi3;
        this.color = color;
    }

    //getters and setters
}

public class Toyota extends CarDiscriminator {

    private int attrToyota1 = 1;
    private int attrToyota2 = 2;
    private int attrToyota3 = 3;
    private ColorDiscriminator color;

    {
        carType = CarType.TOYOTA;
    }

    public Toyota() {}

    public Toyota(int attrToyota1, int attrToyota2, int attrToyota3, ColorDiscriminator color) {
        this.attrToyota1 = attrToyota1;
        this.attrToyota2 = attrToyota2;
        this.attrToyota3 = attrToyota3;
        this.color = color;
    }

    //getters and setters
}

@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        property = "colorType")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Blue.class, name = ColorType.BLUE_STR),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Red.class, name = ColorType.RED_STR)
})
public abstract class ColorDiscriminator {

    protected ColorType colorType;

    //default constructor
 
    //colorType getter and setter
}

public class Blue extends ColorDiscriminator {

    private int attrBlue1 = 1;
    private int attrBlue2 = 2;
    private int attrBlue3 = 3;

    {
        colorType = ColorType.BLUE;
    }

    public Blue() {}

    public Blue(int attrBlue1, int attrBlue2, int attrBlue3) {
        this.attrBlue1 = attrBlue1;
        this.attrBlue2 = attrBlue2;
        this.attrBlue3 = attrBlue3;
    }
   
    //getters and setters
}

public class Red extends ColorDiscriminator {

    private int attrRed1 = 1;
    private int attrRed2 = 2;
    private int attrRed3 = 3;

    {
      colorType = ColorType.RED;
    }

    public Red() {}

    public Red(int attrRed1, int attrRed2, int attrRed3) {
        this.attrRed1 = attrRed1;
        this.attrRed2 = attrRed2;
        this.attrRed3 = attrRed3;
    }

    //getters and setters
}

Here is also another implementation at OneCompiler where you might need to keep carType and colorType with visibility private. Since in this case the child classes cannot access the parents' fields, they provide the value during the serialization with a custom method annotated with @JsonGetter.
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        property = "carType")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Audi.class, name = CarType.AUDI_STR),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Toyota.class, name = CarType.TOYOTA_STR)
})
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public abstract class CarDiscriminator {

    private CarType carType;

    //default constructor

    //carType getter and setter
}

public class Audi extends CarDiscriminator {

    private int attrAudi1 = 1;
    private int attrAudi2 = 2;
    private int attrAudi3 = 3;
    private ColorDiscriminator color;

    public Audi() {}

    public Audi(int attrAudi1, int attrAudi2, int attrAudi3, ColorDiscriminator color) {
        this.attrAudi1 = attrAudi1;
        this.attrAudi2 = attrAudi2;
        this.attrAudi3 = attrAudi3;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @JsonGetter
    public CarType getCarType(){
        return CarType.AUDI;
    }

    //getters and setters
}

public class Toyota extends CarDiscriminator {

    private int attrToyota1 = 1;
    private int attrToyota2 = 2;
    private int attrToyota3 = 3;
    private ColorDiscriminator color;

    public Toyota() {}

    public Toyota(int attrToyota1, int attrToyota2, int attrToyota3, ColorDiscriminator color) {
        this.attrToyota1 = attrToyota1;
        this.attrToyota2 = attrToyota2;
        this.attrToyota3 = attrToyota3;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @JsonGetter
    public CarType getCarType(){
        return CarType.TOYOTA;
    }

    //getters and setters
}

@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        property = "colorType")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Blue.class, name = ColorType.BLUE_STR),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Red.class, name = ColorType.RED_STR)
})
public abstract class ColorDiscriminator {

    private ColorType colorType;

    //default constructor

    //colorType getter and setter
}

public class Blue extends ColorDiscriminator {

    private int attrBlue1 = 1;
    private int attrBlue2 = 2;
    private int attrBlue3 = 3;

    public Blue(){}

    public Blue(int attrBlue1, int attrBlue2, int attrBlue3) {
        this.attrBlue1 = attrBlue1;
        this.attrBlue2 = attrBlue2;
        this.attrBlue3 = attrBlue3;
    }

    @JsonGetter
    public ColorType getColorType(){
        return ColorType.BLUE;
    }

    //getters and setters
}

public class Red extends ColorDiscriminator {

    private int attrRed1 = 1;
    private int attrRed2 = 2;
    private int attrRed3 = 3;

    public Red(){}

    public Red(int attrRed1, int attrRed2, int attrRed3) {
        this.attrRed1 = attrRed1;
        this.attrRed2 = attrRed2;
        this.attrRed3 = attrRed3;
    }

    @JsonGetter
    public ColorType getColorType(){
        return ColorType.RED;
    }

    //getters and setters
}

Here is also a third implementation at OneCompiler where instead of JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY it is used JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY. I imagined that if carType and colorType had no purpose in the code and were used only for deserialization, you might opt for a PROPERTY solution instead of an EXISTING_PROPERTY approach. Here, the discriminator classes have no attributes and act solely as markers.
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "carType")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Audi.class, name = CarType.AUDI_STR),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Toyota.class, name = CarType.TOYOTA_STR)
})
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public abstract class CarDiscriminator {}

public class Audi extends CarDiscriminator {

    private int attrAudi1 = 1;
    private int attrAudi2 = 2;
    private int attrAudi3 = 3;
    private ColorDiscriminator color;

    public Audi(){}

    public Audi(int attrAudi1, int attrAudi2, int attrAudi3, ColorDiscriminator color) {
        this.attrAudi1 = attrAudi1;
        this.attrAudi2 = attrAudi2;
        this.attrAudi3 = attrAudi3;
        this.color = color;
    }

    //getters and setters
}

public class Toyota extends CarDiscriminator {

    private int attrToyota1 = 1;
    private int attrToyota2 = 2;
    private int attrToyota3 = 3;
    private ColorDiscriminator color;

    public Toyota(){}

    public Toyota(int attrToyota1, int attrToyota2, int attrToyota3, ColorDiscriminator color) {
        this.attrToyota1 = attrToyota1;
        this.attrToyota2 = attrToyota2;
        this.attrToyota3 = attrToyota3;
        this.color = color;
    }

    //getters and setters
}

@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "colorType")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Blue.class, name = ColorType.BLUE_STR),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Red.class, name = ColorType.RED_STR)
})
public abstract class ColorDiscriminator {}

public class Blue extends ColorDiscriminator {

    private int attrBlue1 = 1;
    private int attrBlue2 = 2;
    private int attrBlue3 = 3;

    public Blue(){}

    public Blue(int attrBlue1, int attrBlue2, int attrBlue3) {
        this.attrBlue1 = attrBlue1;
        this.attrBlue2 = attrBlue2;
        this.attrBlue3 = attrBlue3;
    }

    //getters and setters
}

public class Red extends ColorDiscriminator {

    private int attrRed1 = 1;
    private int attrRed2 = 2;
    private int attrRed3 = 3;

    public Red(){}

    public Red(int attrRed1, int attrRed2, int attrRed3) {
        this.attrRed1 = attrRed1;
        this.attrRed2 = attrRed2;
        this.attrRed3 = attrRed3;
    }

    //getters and setters
}

Finally, here I'm providing the SimpleBeanPropertyFilter in reference to this Baeldung article.
public class ColorFilter extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter {

    @Override
    public void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider, PropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {
        if (include(writer)) {
            if (!writer.getName().equals("color")) {
                writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
                return;
            }

            if (pojo instanceof Audi) {
                if (((Audi) pojo).getColor() != null) {
                    writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
                    return;
                }
            }

            if (pojo instanceof Toyota) {
                if (((Toyota) pojo).getColor() != null) {
                    writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
                }
            }
        } else if (!jgen.canOmitFields()) { // since 2.3
            writer.serializeAsOmittedField(pojo, jgen, provider);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean include(BeanPropertyWriter writer) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean include(PropertyWriter writer) {
        return true;
    }
}

@JsonFilter("colorFilter")
public class Audi extends CarDiscriminator {
   ...
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        FilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("colorFilter", new ColorFilter());
        ...
    }
}


Thank you for long response. Everything you wrote I agree with. But I think you did not understand my question/problem.

The only sentence that seemed a question was "Scenario where I need to use also two discriminators, but not in "inheritance chain":". The answer is at the beginning: no multiple discriminators are not supported. The rest of my answer only deepens why you shouldn't push for something that tries to mimic multiple inheritance in your json and your code.

If I still misunderstood, please update your question.

I've added json examples I need consume/produce. Hopefully it is now more clear what I want to achieve.

Thank you. You know these two object names (Car: Audi | Toyota, Color: Blue | Red) I used, was just example. You can imagine any other object names that makes more sense. E.g. Car: Audi | Toyota, Owner: Person | Company. Important is: 1. I need use two different discriminators, 2. But not both of them in inheritance chain (which I know is not supported). And to be honest this sentence you mentioned: "JSonSubType annotation only on one of the classes composing an object" is not there written. For me - it is just clear, that in inheritance chain just one discriminator can be used.

@sasynkamil I've updated my answer. Thank you for the further explanation of your question. And yes, when I wrote that sentence about JsonSubType I misspoke. Hope this answers your question.

I created most simple project in SpringBoot 3.3.1, SpringDoc 2.6.0 and multiple discriminators are working correctly. Then I found out that SpringDoc 2.6.0 is fresh version (just 2 days old) and includes fixes connected to discriminator & polymorphism ("oneOf"). Once I upgraded my "complex" project from SpringDoc 2.5.0 > 2.6.0, swagger is generated correctly:

